# How to update a branch after checking out

Tags: git

I am new to Git. I have checked out a branch X from Y. Actually I forgot to do "git pull origin Y" before creating the new branch. Later I checked out to Y and did "git pull origin Y". I want to know how do I get those changes in Y to my branch X that I have cut from Y. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than merging the two branches, especially if you don't have pushed `X` yet, I would rather rebase `X` on top of `Y`.

You started from:

```
y--y--y         (branch Y)
       \
        x--x--x (branch X)
```

You belatedly did the `git pull Y` to update `Y`:

```
y--y--y--y--y   (branch Y)
       \
        x--x--x (branch X)
```

So simply rebase `X` on top of the updated `Y`:

```
git checkout X
git rebase Y

y--y--y--y--y   (branch Y)
             \
              x'--x'--x' (branch X)
```

See "[`git rebase` vs `git merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)" for more.

Answer (score 0):

simply merge the two branches:

```
 # make sure we are on branch master
 git checkout master
 # merge branch Y from origin into master
 git merge origin/Y
```

Comment: So you mean here I should do "git checkout X" and then "git merge Y" to get the changes in Y to X, right?

Comment: @Joy, since you have created your `Y` branch all by itself, you most likely have two different branches `Y` and `origin/Y`; that's why i say that you should do `git merge origin/Y` rather than `git merge Y`.

Comment: @Joy: also you don't need to `git checkout master` if you are already on *master* branch.